# How to use Graph Transform Tool with a savedmodel exported with the estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, proto

If a model is trained using high level estimator API, it can be exported with a call to

```
estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base, serving_input_receiver_fn,
                            strip_default_attrs=True)
```

However, with this approach, the model is saved with the following directory structure:

```
variables/
    variables.data-?????-of-?????
    variables.index
saved_model.pb|saved_model.pbtxt
```

I could not find any way to convert this style (referred to as savedmodel format) to a single freezed graph. 
What I want to achieve is to apply transformations for optimization using the [tensorflow Graph Transform Tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md). This cannot be applied on `saved_model.pb` and fails with the following error:

```
failed with Can't parse...both text and binary parsing failed
```